# animating box shadow when visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We have an image and want to animate the box shadow of it when it is visible on the page by adding a class to it. This below code works for other elements when they're visible but doesn't add the class to the div we want. Maybe .closest isn't the right choice.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="test-thewinner">
<img class="img-winner" src="xxx.png" alt="test-desktop">
<div class="test-shadow"></div>
</div>



              /* highlight border of winner */
    $('.img-winner').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, animate border or box shadow */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

        $(this).closest('.test-shadow').addClass('greenit');

        }

    });
```

Comment: try .siblings('.test-shadow')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes closest is not the right choice, as per the docs

**.closest( selector )**

For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing **up through its ancestors** in the DOM tree.

You can use.

```
$(this).siblings('.test-shadow:first').addClass('greenit');
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely `.closest` is not the right choice, because it will search parents of the element in question. Change it to `$(this).next().addClass('greenit');` or to `$(this).next('.test-shadow').addClass('greenit');` if there may be siblings in between.

Comment: `.next('.test-shadow')` if there are siblings between